# Are there any concurrent queue types in a .NET 3rd party library?

Tags: c#, .net

If I can't use .NET 4, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use the standard [`Queue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c%28VS.80%29.aspx) and use a Monitor ([lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28VS.80%29.aspx)) to synchronize access to the queue.

Comment: @Mauricio, thanks, I am aware of that. But unless tested and confirmed that it would make a significant difference I would rather take the safe option and only if there is a clear benefit would I focus on this particular area of optimization.

Answer (score 2):

[Mono](http://code.google.com/p/mono-soc-2008/source/browse/trunk/parallelfx/System.Threading/System.Threading.Collections/ConcurrentQueue.cs?r=518). (source code link is from 2009, you might want to look it up on [github](https://github.com/mono/mono))